# How do i save php ext dir in a variable?

Tags: php, linux, bash, variables, debian

actually i'm creating a bash script for initial setup for servers with some different software. To install ioncube loader into php i need the php extension directory in a variable.

I already tried something like this: `php -i | grep extension_dir`

but i dont need the output like: `extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20190902 => /usr/lib/php/20190902`

Thats what i need is: `/usr/lib/php/20190902`

Does anybody know how to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
edvar=$(php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');")
echo $edvar
```

Comment: i already understand it (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ini-get.php)

Comment: @yFStein you may, but whoever comes along next might not

Comment: ```./bash.sh: line 3: =/usr/lib/php/20190902: No such file or directory
``` but ```/usr/lib/php/20190902``` exists. Where did the ```=``` coming from?

Comment: php -r

This runs code interactively without <? ?> tags

$()

This runs the command and does an assignment in bash to the variable $edvar

echo $edvar

This should print the return value of the previous command

Comment: ```phpextensiondir="(php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');")"``` | ```syntax error near unexpected token `('```